# Can I use device's biometrics (face id, touch id, etc) on a ReactJS project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example, react-native has [react-native-touch-id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-touch-id-custom) which allows the developer to be able to integrate the use of touch id into their react-native application, I understand that react-native makes this possible because it caters for native mobile application development but I was wondering if there was any JavaScript library, framework, plugin or a piece of code out there that I can use to achieve the same result for a web application? Obviously this will work if the web app is used on a mobile device, if not a standard password will be requested instead.

Reason for this: I already have OTP implemented for my project but I think it'd be a nice feature to enable OTP with a biometric functionality during the login process, instead of asking the user to enter their password and then provide a OTP as well.

The web app will be running on a browser and written in ReactJS, with PHP used as a server side language.

I've done extensive research on this and I've come up blank, I also don't want to use an external hardware like the [CAMS fingerprint scanner](https://camsunit.com/product/javascript-supported-biometric-fingerprint-scanner-CAMS-MFS100-A.html).

I also understand how unlikely this is but I still think there must be some way something remotely close to this can be achieved with the rich JS ecosystem.

Any suggestion and/or idea will be very much appreciated.